# How customize react-table with semantic-ui-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui-react, react-table

I am pretty new developing with React and currently i am using semantic-ui-react.

I would like to use react-table to display the data but i would like display the same style of tables of semantic-ui-react.

How i can set the style of this component with the styles of semantic ui?